# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. - string.Format

Tags: c#, .net

Why do I get this error?

> "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

for the following code?

```
string lookupSchema = "<Field Type='Lookup' DisplayName='{0}' Required='FALSE' EnforceUniqueValues='FALSE' List='{70d6098c-6ba0-4e9e-b101-a60b88fc226a}' ShowField='Title' UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary='FALSE' RelationshipDeleteBehavior='None' StaticName='{0}' Name='{0}'/>";

string columnSchema = string.Format(lookupSchema.ToString(), listOfColumns[1]);
```

Comment: Protip: `listOfColumns[1]`

Comment: Protip 2: `lookupSchema.ToString()` will **always** be `lookupSchema` since it's already a `string` (for the code above - this isn't the case with `null`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for you answers.
As it turns out the problem was in the lookupSchema string due to curly braces. Just changed "List='{70d6098c-6ba0-4e9e-b101-a60b88fc226a}'" to "List='{{70d6098c-6ba0-4e9e-b101-a60b88fc226a}}'" and its working now.